# Trouble getting $id from session in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass on the value $id through my href to the next page

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/offer-me/{id}', 'OffersController@create')->name('project.detailed');
```

**From View:**

```
<a href="{{ route('project.detailed', [$product->id]) }}"><button class="btn btn-success">View</button></p></a>
```

When I go to localhost/projectp0/public/offer-me/2 .... **There is no $id value?**

```
{"_token":"dSxgM8wTlpNxhDKsqj713KMy656bg8XAU5Q2sqe4","_previous":{"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/projectp0\/public\/auction"},"_flash":{"old":[],"new":[]},"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d":1}
```

To get that view i Run:

```
   $data = session()->all();
   return($data)
```

Comment: What is your use case? That could be helpful to get you a proper solution/alternative.

Comment: `$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);` (note the associative array with the `id` key mapping to the value)

Comment: @HCK I have a form on the other end i want to store the value in  $product->id= $id

Comment: @drew010 same error. No $id value is shown even when i try             $data = $request->session()->get('id'); and return it

Comment: Looks like there is no `$product` anywhere in the data passed to the view. Once that is passed in, the URL `route` helper will generate the URL correctly.

Comment: @drew010 can we discuss it in chat?

Comment: its not in the session, its part of the url, its a route parameter

Answer (score 1):

The `{id}` parameter lives in the request, and not in the session.

It will be available as `request()->id`.

Answer (score 0):

The Returned Data set is your session data. Session data is not storing the data you send from a Get Method. Get method send Data with the URL,

So create method in Offer Controller should be like this.....

```
public function create($id){
      dd($id);
}
```

Then You Can see What is the value passed for the $id,

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
public function create($id)
{

}
```

It is better to have a create route use a post route
in which case you should be able to access it through the request

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @drew010 suggested you in comments, try this way :

```
<a href="{{ route('project.detailed', ['id' => $product->id]) }}"><button class="btn btn-success">View</button></p></a>
```